# If you roll a fair die 3 times, what is the probability that all 3 rolls will come up a value less than 4

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

If you roll a fair die 3 times, what is the probability that all 3 rolls will come up a value less than 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired probability is $\frac{1}{8}$. To see why, note that the probability of the number being less than $4$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ in each roll of the dice. These can just be multiplied to give the probability of $\frac{1}{8}$.